# ¿como asignar un valor a una variable que ya está encapsulada?

Tags: java

este es el enunciado

una clase denominada Empleado por Comisión que tiene los atributos
primer nombre, primer apellido, número seguro social, venta bruta y tarifa comisión.
En la misma clase hay un constructor que recibe cinco (5) parámetros de entrada
para cada uno de los atributos definidos y que se asignan a través del this.
También están definidos los respectivos métodos getters para cada uno de los
atributos.
 Se debe definir el método setVentasBrutas que recibe un parámetro de entrada
denominado ventasBrutas de tipo double, dentro del método se debe validar que
el parámetro de entrada sea mayor o igual a 0.0, si el valor cumple la condición se
asignar al atributo ventasBrutas que está encapsulado y tiene el tipo de dato
double.
 Se debe definir el método setTarifaComision que recibe un parámetro de entrada
denominado tarifaComision de tipo double, dentro del método se debe validar que
este parámetro no sea menor o igual a 0.0 o mayor o igual a 1.0, si es así se debe
indicar que la tarifa de comisión no es correcta, pero si está dentro del rango
definido se asigna el valor del parámetro de entrada al atributo tarifaComision que
está encapsulado y tiene el tipo de dato double.

 Se debe definir el método ingreso que se encarga de retornar el producto de los
atributos tarifaComision y ventasBrutas.

 Existe una clase cliente denominada Prueba Empleado por Comisión donde se
instancia la clase EmpleadoPorComision y se obtiene el primer nombre, el primer
apellido y el numero de seguro social para el empleado. También se define las
ventas brutas, la tarifa de comisión y finalmente se calcula los ingresos del
empleado.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. La idea es que lo intentes tú por tu cuenta y si tienes algún problema, muestres tu código, expliques dónde está el problema, cuál es el resultado obtenido y cuál es el resultado deseado. Puede leer [mcve] como referencia. No le hacemos los deberes o tareas a nadie. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, el título de tu pregunta es clara, y ahora te la voy a responder, pero deberías escribir algo de código, por lo menos una porción donde tenés dudas. Editá la pregunta añadiendo código así te podemos ayudar

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo al título de la pregunta: Cuando un **atributo o propiedad** se encapsula, por ejemplo con el modificador de acceso `private` (el más común), se logra impedir el acceso a ese **atributo o propiedad** por fuera de esta clase. Por lo tanto cuando desees acceder a dicho atributo desde otra clase, ya sea tanto para obtener el valor como también asignar un valor, lo vas a hacer mediante métodos que por convención se nombran con getNombreAtributo para acceder al valor y setNombreAtributo para asignar un valor, ej.: `getVentaBruta()`. Entonces para asignar un valor a `VentaBruta` desde la clase `PruebaEmpleadoPorComision` vas a instanciar el objeto `EmpleadoPorComision` y le vas a ejecutar el método `setVentaBruta(valor)`. Algo así:

```
EmpleadoPorComision emp1=new EmpleadoPorComision(valor,valor,valor,valor,valor);
emp1.setVentaBruta(otroValor);
```